# How can i retrieve information for a cgi program on an onther cgi program

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am currently working on a color blindness simulator for school, I use python and CGI. You can translate a default image through the website, it uses CGI and it works. You can also upload an image (it uses CGI too), but if you want to translate the image you've just uploaded, you can't because the CGI program won't retrieve the information from the other cgi program. any idea how I could do that?

```
<form action = "/cgi-bin/supression.py" >
<input type="radio" name="type" value="normal">Normal<br> 
 <input type="radio" name="type" value="protanopie">Protanopie<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value="deuteranopie">Deuteranopie<br>
<p><input id="btn2" type="submit" value="Traduire"/></p>
</form>

cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if form.getvalue('type'):
 type = form.getvalue('type')
if type == "protanopie":
 modif_image("image.jpg","protanope")
elif type == "deuteranopie":
 modif_image("image.jpg","deuteranopie")
```

Comment: What does your `modif_image` function??

Comment: It changes the color of the image.

Comment: And it doesn't return the result? Nor saves it on disk?

Comment: Nope, it only return the result when the program gets the form value from the html file, nothing comes out when the program gets the form value from the cgi file printing html

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to store the data between different requests. You can do this differently:

1. Store in Python variables. For this you need to make your script working permanently, i.e able to handle multiple requests with loosing global variable values. Consider using some advanced framework for this, [e.g. Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org). It will also allow you to create different pages of your web application, whatever you wish: for new files uploading, for viewing already uploaded ones, etc.
2. Use a database (e.g builtin [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)) and/or store the given files on disk (just google `Python open read write files`, for pictures you need to deal with binary files).